# Soap client paramaters not response on Php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I succeeded with SOAPUI, but it is not working on php.
SOAP:

SOAP Client Call & Response

[image]

and php codes

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$url = "http://bla.bla.bla.bla/WSAndroid/Service1.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$a = $client->__getFunctions(); 
var_dump($a);
$params = array(
  "username" => "bla_username",
  "password" => "bla_password",
  "ogrencino" => "bla_ogrencino",
  "sifre" => "bla_sifre"
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("KimlikDogrula",$params);
var_dump($response);
```

Response :

> object(stdClass)#2 (1) {   ["KimlikDogrulaResult"]=>
>   object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
>       ["Hata"]=>
>       bool(true)
>       ["HataMesaji"]=>
>       string(16) "Yetkisiz"
>       ["Sinifi"]=>
>       int(0)   } }

Follow request with Charles for params information:

[image]

Where am I making a mistake in my php code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Explain specifically what is not working.

Comment: parameters problem.. not response php

Comment: http://193.140.168.45/WSAndroid/Service1.asmx?WSDL this wsdl. How to write UzemKimlikDogrula function parameters on php codes ??